# Too many renderers when using useState for spinner

Tags: javascript, hook

there. I need to make loading spinner with hook, while my component counts some data.
And when it's done it spinner should stop.
But when i set useHook to true, i recieve infinite re-renderers.

```
const myCard = () => {
  [loading, setLoading] = useState()
  if (condition) {
    setLoading(true)
   
   //Some countiong


   // When it's over set loading
   setLoading(false)
  }

  return (
    <Card loading={loading}>
       ...Some card content
    </Card>
  )
}
```

Could anyone tell me what am i doing wrang here ?

Comment: Is the counting done in an async callback? If not, the `setLoading()` will re-render the component indefinitely.

Comment: @TsvetanGanev No there are no async callback

Comment: @p4avinash No, i don't use useEffect.
Because i don't have any varriables to use it with

Comment: You've not given any initial state value..??

Comment: Try putting false in the initial state

Comment: unfortunatelly i don't change anything in initial state,
I could make action in redux setLoading(true)
But my redux is overloaded with many functions already

Comment: Better practice would be always provide a initial value for every state. And if redux is applied to your app. The purpose of redux is to make state management easy plus to also make the state immutable. So that no one changes the state directly. And i wonder what would be the initial state for the loading.

Comment: To change something in the state, there should be some initial value in the state first.

Comment: @p4avinash Unfortunatelly redux is not an option for me at all.
It would be the easiest way, but i  need to find something else.

Answer (score 1):

Put your loading logic inside the useEffect Hook

```
 const myCard = () => {
    [loading, setLoading] = useState(false) //always specify an initial value

    useEffect(() => {
       if (condition) {
        setLoading(true)
       
       //Some countiong
    
    
       // When it's over set loading
       setLoading(false)
      }
  },[condition]) //will render when condition change
      
    
      return (
        <Card loading={loading}>
           ...Some card content
        </Card>
      )
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for answer.
Although for me after setLoading(true), loading is still false.
Inspite useEffect was trigered and if condition also